# reactJS open a .pdf file from an external repository

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I have a reactJS application hosted on AWS in an S3 instance. I also have a web site hosted on AWS in a different S3 instance.  On the web site, I host a bunch of .pdf files.  Lets assume I have 3 .pdf files located at:

> https://www.mywebsite.com/pdffiles/file001.pdf
>   https://www.mywebsite.com/pdffiles/file002.pdf
>   https://www.mywebsite.com/pdffiles/file003.pdf

Is there a way for me to provide my reactJS application users with a series of links to the external .pdf files?  I tried the following code:

```
renderDocuments = () => {  
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="documents_background">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 text-left text_14">
                        <label>Below are the links to the participant forms we have available for download.&nbsp;&nbsp;The forms are
                        in .pdf format.&nbsp;&nbsp;You will need to have Adabe Acrobat Reader installed in order to view these files.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-9 text-left text_14">
                        <label>Form 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-2 text-right text_14">
                        <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/pdffiles/file001.pdf" Target="_blank" >Download</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-9 text-left text_14">
                        <label>Form 2</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-2 text-right text_14">
                        <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/pdffiles/file002.pdf" Target="_blank" >Download</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-9 text-left text_14">
                        <label>Form 3</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-2 text-right text_14">
                        <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/pdffiles/file003.pdf" Target="_blank" >Download</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

when I click on the hyperlink for form 1, I get the following in the console.log:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "https://www.accurecord-direct.com/dotnet/PDFFILES/VSTA/vstm_enrollment_form.pdf"

The .pdf file does not open and the application just sits there waiting.

Thanks.

Comment: #1, it should be target, not Target. #2, are you sure you're using `<a />` and not something like `<Link to` or some other type of link (Like from a router)? Your code should work fine now. Clicking on the link, should simply open it in a new tab.

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks!  very strange that just changing the "T" to "t" would resolve this issue.